# Make an anchor tag stretch to be the size of its background image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to display an icon as a background image behind a number.

`<a id="youhavemail" href="messages.php">0</a>`

```
#youhavemail {
  background-image: url("images/mail.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px auto;
}
```

But since there is only one character in the anchor tag (in this case a '0') it only shows a small portion of the image.

Is there a way to stretch the containing anchor to show the whole background image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#youhavemail {
  background-image: url("http://linenwoods.com/images/offline.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```